# Select image and submit it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am developing a gallery for instagram, and I have the users pic displayed on an html page, what I want is for the user to be able to select some of the pics and by clicking a button the picture urls will be sended to my email. Thanks in advance,

Here is the code where images are displayed:

```
$<?php
$popular = $instagram->getUserMedia($data->user->id);

Display results
foreach ($popular->data as $data) {
  echo "<img src=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\">";

}

?>
```

Preview: [image]

I want something similar to this:
http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

The part where it says selects multiple, but whith a button that will send the urls of all the selected pics.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/. It seems good

```
<select id="myId">
<?php foreach ($popular->data as $data): ?>
    <option data-img-src='<?php echo $data->images->thumbnail->url ?>' value='<?php echo $data->images->thumbnail->url ?>'>blah blah</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { // code required jquery and image picker. Add those in head section
        $("#myId").imagepicker(); // you can pass param too customize it in your manner
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Added the code but images are not showing up only an empy select box,